# Simple Vectorized Math on Multilevel Columns by Level=0 as Group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(*[['one', 'one', 'two', 'two'],['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar']])))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape((3,4)), columns=index)

  one     two    
  foo bar foo bar
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
2   8   9  10  11
```

Is there a way to do simple vectorized calculations (like addition) for each level 0 group columns on each of the level 1 columns **without** having to reference the specific column level pairs like:

```
df[('one','add')] = df[('one','foo')]+df[('one','bar')]
```

I'd like to get

```
  one          two      
  foo bar add  foo bar add
0   0   1   1    2   3   5
1   4   5   9    6   7  13
2   8   9  17   10  11  21
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fiddled around with it for a bit and here is a one-liner that solves the problem in my opinion. It's fully vectorized and doesn't address specific column names. It also puts the `add` column in the right place.

```py
df.stack(0).assign(add=df.stack(0).sum(axis=1)).stack(0).unstack(0).T
```

[image]

Unfortunately, because of the property of stack / unstack to do the stacking / unstacking into the innermost level, it needs the cryptic `.stack(0).unstack(0)` operation. It seems like those two operations should cancel each other out, but they actually shuffle the index levels while preserving order.

Here is the same thing split into 3 lines without assign statement.

```py
df = df.stack(0)
df['add'] = df.sum(axis=1)
df = df.stack(0).unstack(0).T
```

Comment: is there a way to address specific column names?

Comment: Probably something like `df['add'] = df[['col1','col2']].sum(axis=1)` would do that.

Comment: The following are single line representations of adding and dividing: `df.stack(0).assign(div=df.stack(0)['bar']/df.stack(0)['foo']).stack(0).unstack(0).T` `df.stack(0).assign(add=df.stack(0[['bar','foo']].sum(axis=1)).stack(0).unstack(0).T<code>`

Comment: I think there is a bracket missing in your code. 
It should be like this i think:
`.assign(add=df.stack(0)[['bar','foo']].sum(axis=1))`

Comment: cool one liner.  how fast is it compared to the other proposed solutions? Would be a helpful guide.

Answer (score 2):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.sum` with `axis=1` and `level=0`:

```
df2 = df.sum(axis=1, level=0)
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
   one  two
0    1    5
1    9   13
2   17   21
```

You can then add new column names to `pandas.concat`:

```
df2.columns = [(c, "add") for c in df2]
df2 = pd.concat([df, df2], 1).sort_index(1)
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
  one         two        
  add bar foo add bar foo
0   1   1   0   5   3   2
1   9   5   4  13   7   6
2  17   9   8  21  11  10
```

Comment: is there a way to specify column names?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution, here, using the same sum solution, but without `pd.concat` :

```
df[("one", "add")] = None
df[("two", "add")] = None
df.iloc[:, -2:] = df.sum(axis=1, level=0).to_numpy()
df.sort_index(1)
    one              two
     add    bar foo  add    bar foo
0    1.0    1   0    5.0     3  2
1    9.0    5   4    13.0   7   6
2    17.0   9   8    21.0   11  10
```

Comment: is there a way to specify column names?